# SFINAE for unsigned type selection

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I'm trying to use `SFINAE` to check if a type has an `unsigned` equivalent. While it seems to work for `int` and `bool`, it fails for `float`. From the error it seems a certain type is not defined. The question is if the template argument to `enable_if` is ill-formed, why isn't this removed from overload selection ?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<sizeof(std::make_unsigned<T>), bool> hasUnsigned(T x)
{
   return true;
}

bool hasUnsigned(...)
{
   return false;
}

int main()
{
   float x; // If it's int, or char, it below displays true
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << hasUnsigned(x) << std::endl;
}
```

Error with `float`

```
In file included from has_unsigned.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::make_unsigned<float>’:
has_unsigned.cc:5:18:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> std::enable_if_t<(sizeof (std::make_unsigned<_Tp>) != 0), bool> hasUnsigned(T) [with T = float]’
has_unsigned.cc:18:48:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10/type_traits:1826:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::__make_unsigned_selector<float, false, false>’
 1826 |     { typedef typename __make_unsigned_selector<_Tp>::__type type; };
      |                                                              ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/type_traits:1733:11: note: declaration of ‘class std::__make_unsigned_selector<float, false, false>’
 1733 |     class __make_unsigned_selector;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `make_unsigned` on an invalid type (see below) which makes the behavior undefined or program ill-formed. A better approach would be to check if it's an integer:

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool>
```

From [`std::make_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned):

- If `T` is an integral (except `bool`) or enumeration type, provides the member typedef type which is the unsigned integer type corresponding to `T`, with the same cv-qualifiers.
- If `T` is `signed` or `unsigned` `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`; the `unsigned` type from this list corresponding to `T` is provided.
- If `T` is an enumeration type or `char`, `wchar_t`, `char8_t` (since C++20), `char16_t`, `char32_t`; the `unsigned` integer type with the smallest rank having the same `sizeof` as `T` is provided.

Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. (until C++20)
Otherwise, the program is ill-formed. (since C++20)

Comment: If the program is ill-formed, should SFINAE not kick in and use the other overload ?

Comment: @user3882729 from cppreference.com "Only the failures in the types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type or its template parameter types or its explicit specifier (since C++20) are SFINAE errors." I think that's the issue here. `make_unsigned<float>` can be resolved ok, the error occurs in its instantiation. (I'm probably using incorrect terminology, but I hope you catch my meaning).